# Advanced usage of Ajax Control Toolkit MaskedEdit Extender

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

How can I achieve the following with the Ajax Control Toolkit MaskedEdit extender?

Letter + Any number of numeric chararacter such as Z234, Z235, Z24, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [it may not be possible](http://forums.asp.net/t/1338427.aspx)....

Comment: It will allow 9 letters ie. ABCDEFFYY. {} seems to be used for repeating.

Comment: I can't find specific documentation; but my interpretation was that it meant 1 letter followed by repetitions of 1 number. This was just my first stab - I haven't tested it and I can't find anything to indicate if it is right or wrong. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm not in the position to test at the moment, so I'm just guessing... Perhaps L9{} might work. Essentially I'm guessing that {} will allow an indeterminate number of numbers. Might not work, might even insist on patterns like L9L9L9L9... etc. I still can't find any more detailed documentation or any more relevant examples. I'll try later when I get back to my machine.

Answer (score 0):

mask="A999" isn't it working? If its always in format Z[number][number][number] ... try mask="Z999".